# My Permissions Interface Is Not Working Properly For Android API 24 And Upwards

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to create a code that as soon the app begins, it asks for permissions ( WRITE and CAMERA ). If one or all permissions are denied then the app shows a warning text (in TextView ) asking for permissions and also a button “Permission” ( also made from a TextView ) that WILL REMAIN VISIBLE while the user keeps denying any or all these permissions.

This app prototype works fine in the emulator API 23, but in the emulator API 24 and upwards it did not work properly.

Here are the codes:

1) AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lf.permissionsfromlf">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

2) activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permissionNote"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        android:text="@string/give_permission"
        android:textColor="#000066"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/permission_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/permission_btn"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        android:text="@string/permission"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/permissionNote" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

3) MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    TextView permissionNote;
    TextView permission_btn;
    boolean WRITE_GRANTED = false;
    boolean CAMERA_GRANTED = false;
    static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ///////////
        permissionNote =  findViewById(R.id.permissionNote);
        permission_btn =  findViewById(R.id.permission_btn);
        permissionNote.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        permission_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Sets OnClick for the PERMISSION BUTTON in case it becomes necessary
        permission_btn.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if( !WRITE_GRANTED || !CAMERA_GRANTED )
                request_permission();
            }
        });

        //VERIFY IF PERMISSIONS ARE GRANTED for SDK_INT >= 23
        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 )
        {
            //Verifies if permission was already granted
            if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED))
            {
                permissionNote.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                permission_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                request_permission();
            }
            else
            {
                // Permission has already been granted
                permissionNote.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                permission_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            //////////////////////
            if( WRITE_GRANTED && CAMERA_GRANTED )
            {
                // Permission has already been granted
                permissionNote.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                permission_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            //////////////////////
        }
    }

    public void request_permission()
    {
        if(!WRITE_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
        if(!CAMERA_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
        ////////////////////////
        // IF ALL PERMISSIONS ARE GRANTED, MAKE PERMISSION BUTTON INVISIBLE
        if(write_permission_granted())
        {
            WRITE_GRANTED = true;
        }
        if(camera_permission_granted())
        {
            CAMERA_GRANTED = true;
        }

    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE:
        {
            // If request is cancelled, the resulting arrays is empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                // Calling write_permission_granted and camera_permission_granted() after
                // onRequestPermissionsResult
                // updates write_permission and camera permission as to make the PERMISSION BUTTON invisible
                if(write_permission_granted() && camera_permission_granted()) //CAMERA_GRANTED = true;
                {
                    permissionNote.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    permission_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            return;
        }
    }

}




    public boolean write_permission_granted()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public boolean camera_permission_granted()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

So the idea is that the warning and the button will remain visible in the
 screen in case the user changes his mind and clicks the button in order to give
 all permissions. Once all the permissions are given then immediately the
 warning and the button SHOULD DISAPPEAR ( become invisible ).

In the API 24 emulator, when the app starts, only a popup box with the question
 “Allow the app to access photos, media, and files on your device?” appears.
 After answering this one, it  should also popup a second box with the question
 ”Allow this app to take pictures and record video?” BUT IT DOES NOT HAPPEN. As
 consequence, the warning and the button “PERMISSION” remain on the screen. 
So, after that, when I click on this button in the first time it does not respond.
 In the second time when I click again it finally pops up the box 
“Allow this app to  take pictures...”. Only after this second permission is
 finally given, only then the warning and the button disappear ( become
 invisible ) but this should  have happened right at the start of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You fire two permission requests at the same time. The first request shows a dialog. The second request is silently canceled because another permission dialog is already showing. You can verify that by checking `permissions.length == 0` in `onRequestPermissionsResult` (empty arrays mean cancelled request).

Don't fire different permission requests with the same request code.

Put both permissions into a single request.

Comment: Hi Eugen, Thank you for your input. I am a novice in android programming. Could you please tell me how to put both permissions into a single request ? My search about this problem led me to pages where people were using different classes and methods and I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out !

It was way simpler than I imagined.

I should just create a string array to store my permissions:

```
private String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
```

And then in the `public void request_permission()` method, I did this change:

```
if(!WRITE_GRANTED || !CAMERA_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissions, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant by "Put both permissions into a single request." I'm glad you made it work!

Comment: Thank you again, Eugen. If it was not for your tip, I would not have figured it out.